# seekbar thumb onclicklistener

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-seekbar

I need to customize default android seekbar to control music player. I know this sounds very simple, but I just don't know how to set up seekbar **thumb** listener. I want to control music and change icon accordingly to play and pause when user press on seekbar thumb icon. How can I achieve this? I know that this is possible because I previously saw apps like PocketGuide where this functionality is implemented. Here's the screenshot from PocketGuide app [image]

Comment: The simplest way to archive this (in my opinion) is to create a CustomView for this. If you want i could answer with an example to archive this.

Comment: @Kenny Seyffarth it would be amazing. I just need to control some action by pressing on seekbar thumb

Comment: the Thumb is a drawable so you can't directly set a click listener 
but setting OnSeekBarChangeListener would notify you about the touch begin in onStartTrackingTouch and touch up in onStopTrackingTouch
if the value didn't change then it's a click on the thumb

Comment: This sounds more efficient then my answer. :D

Comment: Made little tests with the answer from @zombie, if your max progress is realy high (>1000), then it could be problematically. The sensitivity is really high. See: StartTouch[11-10 14:42:12.100 5365-5365 Seeker: progr: 136255] 
stopTouch[11-10 14:42:12.100 5365-5365 Seeker: progr: 138532]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps you. Adjust the code for your needs.

```
public class SeekbarWithThumbTouch extends SeekBar {

    private int     scaledTouchSlop = 0;
    private float   initTouchX      = 0;
    private boolean thumbPressed    = false;

    public SeekbarWithThumbTouch(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public SeekbarWithThumbTouch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public SeekbarWithThumbTouch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        scaledTouchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        Drawable thumb = null;
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                thumb = getThumb();//works only for API >=16!
                if (thumb != null) {
                    //contains current position of thumb in view as bounds
                    RectF bounds = new RectF(thumb.getBounds());
                    thumbPressed = bounds.contains(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    if (thumbPressed) {
                        Log.d("Thumb", "pressed");
                        initTouchX = event.getX();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (thumbPressed) {
                    Log.d("Thumb", "was pressed -- listener call");
                    thumbPressed = false;
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (thumbPressed) {
                    if (Math.abs(initTouchX - event.getX()) > scaledTouchSlop) {
                        initTouchX = 0;
                        thumbPressed = false;
                        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
                    Log.d("Thumb", "move blocked");
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```